# Can't name symbolic link to java file other than name of the java file

Tags: java, bash, symlink

Take a look at the following picture:[image]

I make a symbolic link to java .class file. And it works, I can pass the original file to Java interpreter via symbolic link, and it runs program normally. But if I name link any other than original file name, it doesn't work.

It frustrates me that I have to name it like original file name.

Not sure should I have posted this to Unix/Linux stack.

Comment: in Java the file containing a class has to have the the same name as the class. But you could create a runnable Jar from your class (files) and that can have any name you like.

Comment: A java class must end with .class and will its name will be used to get the class's name

Comment: Well class is called after the file it is in. Both file and class are named App. Actualy class is App, files are App.java and App.class

Comment: well i've never renamed the java file, just the symlink

Comment: If you want to use java, you have to follow naming rules of the platform. I don't think there's much to say

Comment: Does anyone understand that java file and java class both have the same names??? It's only the symlink I change the name of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a requirement because that's how Java **finds** the class file.

When you say `java App`, the `App` is not a file name, but a fully-qualified class name.

Java has some rules how to get from a class name to a file name. This is implemented in the default class loader. When the class is stored in a .class file (rather than a .jar file), it automatically appends the `.class` extension to the class name. 
Before it does that, it translates the package separator (which looks like a dot in Java source code) into the path separator of your operating system (on Linux, a `/` (slash), and on Windows a `\` (backslash).

If you give the class file a different name, whether you do that with a real rename or with a symlink, Java is just not able to find it, because it doesn't follow the Java rules on how to get from a class name to a file name.